# İmage scraping from subreddit with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, reddit, praw

I'm trying to make a tool that will take photos from any subreddit with python and save them in a specific folder.I can do this, but when I want to use it, I will have to make changes by opening the codes. How can I do this by getting input from the terminal? Like here,

```
python main.py -s <subreddit> -d <directory> -u <url> -c <category> -l <limit>
```

Comment: Are you just asking for people to code such utility for you or will you provide some code to discuss about?

Comment: @Nastor I'm just asking how can I do it.

Comment: I didn't get it, you already had working code and simply asking how to interact with the program from command line. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accept arguments in your function:

```
def scraper(sub, directory, url, category, limit):
    #your code
```

So everything after the running of the script will be in those arguments:

```
python3 testing.py subreddit directory url category limit
```

If you don't know how many inputs you are expecting use `**args` or `**kwargs`:

```
def scraper(**args)
```

You can read more about args and kwargs [here](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html)

**EDIT:** You can use `sys.argv[1]` to get certain arguments, **make sure to import sys**:

```
subreddit = sys.argv[1]
```

If I typed "python3 script.py banana" and printed the variable "subreddit", the output of the code above would be "banana"

Answer (score 0):

You can parse command line arguments with e.g. the `argparse` package.